# why does the last correct answer still work?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

this is a quiz website, but when i submit answer and its correct a new question pops up but correct answer and last correct answer works (last correct works unlimited until new last answer) ive tried for hours to fix it and see no solution... last correct answer isnt suppose to work with new question

```js
var right = 0
function start(){
 var name = $('input#answer').val()
 if ($.trim(name) != ''){
  $.post('ajax/name.php', {name: name}, function(data){
   $('#correctbox').text(data)
  if (name == data){
   rightfunc()
   rand()
  }else{
   rand()
  }
  } )
 }
}
function rand(){
  $.post('ajax/test.php', {name: name}, function(data){
   $('#questionsbox').text(data)
   document.getElementById("answer").value = '';
  } )
}
function rightfunc(){
 right = right + 1
 rightbox.innerHTML = "<b>Correct | "+right+"</b>"
}
```

```html
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name']) === true && empty($_POST['name']) === false){

 require '../db/connect.php';
 mysql_set_charset('utf8');
 $name = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(addslashes(trim($_POST['name']))));
 $query = ("SELECT *
 FROM japanese 
 WHERE Romanji = '$name'
 ")or die(mysql_error());
 
 $response = mysql_query($query);
   
 if($response === false){
  die(mysql_error());
 }
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($response)){
  if($name == $row['Romanji']){
   echo ($row['Romanji']);
  }else{
   echo ('Name not found');
  }
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Post your form html, or whatever you are using to trigger the ajax.

Answer (score 0):

When you give a correct answer you don't empty the `input#answer` :

```
.post('ajax/name.php', {name: name}, function(data){
            $('#correctbox').text(data);
            //add next line so you can remove it from rand()
            document.getElementById("answer").value = '';
        if (name == data){
            rightfunc()
            rand()
        }else{
            rand()
        }
        } )
```

And another thing is why you always sent the same query to database? if your questions change, your query shouldn't be different ?

Comment: function start(){
 .post('ajax/name.php', {name: name}, function(data){
            $('#correctbox').text(data);
            //add next line so you can remove it from rand()
            document.getElementById("answer").value = '';
        if (name == data){
            rightfunc()
            rand()
        }else{
            rand()
        }
        } )
}

Comment: With what you said I'm assuming that your code send the last value of `input#answer` over and over without writing new value which is the java problem indeed but my question is why your query (in php page) is the same every time question change? I mean user can write the last correct answer (even if you make `var name = null`), send it and get point. There is no connection between your query and your question.